# Regex to get a name from parentheses without spaces

Tags: regex

I'm trying to get the file name between two parentheses that can contain spaces between the name and any parentheses.
example:
(   file_name    )

I used the regex:

```
(([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*)[ \t]*)
```

The problem is that, it matches the file_name with the spaces before and after it. 
I want to match the file_name without the spaces.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just use `\b[A-Za-z_]\w*\b` to match whole words that only consist of word chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add \s* outside the capturing parenthesis. (also you need to escape the outermost parenthesis if you want to match a litteral parenthesis) :

```
\(\s*([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*)\s*\)
```

Comment: Thanks Eino for your answer. It does not work with escaping the parentheses. Without escaping the parentheses, it gives me the file_name with the spaces before it and without the spaces after it. Now, we need to remove the spaces before it.

Comment: Can you give us an example of exact string you want to match (are there parenthesis in there) ? I understood it's "(  file_name  )" and you want to match file_name

Comment: I'm writing a parser that reads a file using Lex. When it founds "include ( file_name   )", it extracts the file_name and opens it to continue reading from it. The "fopen" function gives an error if the file name contains spaces before or after. Thus, I want to extract the file name without any spaces before or after.

Comment: Then something like this should work : `include\s*\(\s*([A-Za-z_][\w\.]*)\s*\)`. Cf [example on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/FOlK2Y/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
\(\s*(\S+)\s*\)
```

and take the first group, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/0a0uCa/1).

---

Explained:

```
\(    # match ( literally
\s*   # zero or more whitespaces
(\S+) # capture anything not a whitespace, at least one character
\s*.  # same as above
\)    # match ) literally
```

Comment: Thanks Jan for your answer, but it does not work; it just gives me "S"